# Find out which apple music songs are playable in your country (e.g. via track_id)

Tags: ios, swift, apple-music, itunes-search-api

Using the [apple itunes search api](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/) it is possible to get information on songs such as artist, title and apple store track_id:
[image]

Using an MPMusicPlayerController (i tried both system and application) one should be able to play songs using:

```
player = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
player.setQueueWithStoreIDs(["574050602"])
player.play()
```

[As noted here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46666) some IDs seem to not work. (e.g. "574050602" is supposed to play a certain song by Rick Astley)

I have read that you need a country specific store id.

How can I determine whether a specific song will be playable or not without actually trying to play it?

The `isStreamable` property does not indicate whether I can actually stream it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only get track IDs that are playable in your country you need to specify your country on search using the `country` parameter ([source](https://bendodson.com/weblog/2016/02/26/storefront-additions-skcloudservicecontroller-to-country-code/))

I have not found out what kind of problems the author at [1](https://bendodson.com/weblog/2016/02/26/storefront-additions-skcloudservicecontroller-to-country-code/) had with this parameter, but there also seems to be an undocumented parameter `s` which might help.

Answer (score 0):

The trackIDs are not shareable between countries. Therefore you will need to let the user get their own countries' trackID code by performing an API request with the user's countrycode.